# Turn an Expr into an array in julia

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I have an Expr

```
:([4.01673077 7.62137432 8.74459436 10.14775067 12.57379884 14.39781963; 17.00925227 19.2273262])
```

and I wish to transfer it into a Vector{Float64}, but calling `eval` on this directly does not seem to work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either extract the data from `Expr` (faster and safe) or just `eval` it (slower, unsafe, easier code).

```
julia> a  = :([12.57379884 14.39781963; 17.00925227 19.2273262])
:([12.57379884 14.39781963; 17.00925227 19.2273262])

julia> [Float64.(vals) for vals in getfield.(a.args, :args)]
2-element Vector{Vector{Float64}}:
 [12.57379884, 14.39781963]
 [17.00925227, 19.2273262]

julia> eval(a)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 12.5738  14.3978
 17.0093  19.2273
```

Your matrix is wrongly formed and hence only the first solution will work with it.

Comment: I thought there might be some operation on Expr directly changing ';' to ',' as in the String. But the answer is great. Thank you! Przemyslaw.

Comment: You could do something like ` JSON3.read(replace(replace(string(a),' '=>','),";,"=>","))` but this is not too much elegant.